# How to automatically push data from Excel file to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How can one push data from an Excel file into my SQL Server?

---

I tried to get data from the database into an Excel file but I don't know how to push the new data and the users won't click the button to push data every time.

So if someone knows how to sync a SQL Server database with the Excel files in order to get that data automatically, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you looked into SSIS?

Comment: What @WEI_DBA said along with a SQL agent job (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-2017) to automatically run that SSIS package.

Comment: @WEI_DBA what is that? That is the first time i read and hear about it

Comment: SQL Server Integration Services... Start here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-create-a-project-and-basic-package-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push data from excel to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037198/how-to-push-data-from-excel-to-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will look forward to two options in this scenario:

**SSIS Package:**
Use SSIS package which picks up data from a specified path (your excel), which inserts new rows and updates existing ones. Schedule this package with SQL Job agent.

**Console App:**
Write a simple c# console app, which does the same and schedules it using windows scheduler.

Comment: Does the SSIS Package work on a local sql Server? Cause I use a local sql Server

Comment: Sure it does, you just need to set up Integration Services on your local server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017